# Parse Cloud JavaScript Save Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In Parse Cloud code, I saw a period of code like this:

```
myObject.save(null, {
   success:function(){}
   error:function(error){}
});
```

Is the "null" means i want to do nothing special but save in the saving step?
If that, can I just delete the "null"?

Additionally:

the delete object function destroy:

```
myObject.destroy({EXAMPLE}{
     success: function(myObject) {
 },
error: function(myObject, error) {
 }
});
```

If I add a function in the "EXAMPLE" place, will the function be called? if Yes, what is the order of the calling, after the destroy function or before the destroy function.

Comment: No you can't delete it because otherwise the object becomes parameter 0 when it's expected at parameter 1 so the callbacks won't get implemented.

Comment: Thx!Then how about the destroy function, is it a parameter 1 or 0 function? I'm pretty new to javascript, so is it means that if the function is parameter 1, you have to give it a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the first part of the question, no. You can't delete it because otherwise the object after the null that contains the success and fail functions becomes parameter 0 (i.e. the first parameter you pass into the `destroy` function). Since `destroy()` expects it at parameter 1 (i.e. the second parameter), the `success` and `fail` functions won't get called.

To the second part: any parameter you pass into a function is just 'dead' data unless the function does something with it. The definition for the `destroy` function would look something like this:

```
destroy: function(thingToDelete, callbacks){
    // destroy thingToDelete
    if(success){
        callbacks.success();
    } else {
        callbacks.fail();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the first parameter (parameter 0, `thingToDelete`) doesn't get **called**, it gets **deleted**. So whatever you replace `{EXAMPLE}` with, the `destroy` function will try to delete it not call it. And as you can also see, if you omit the first parameter (`null` in your first example), the object containing `success` and `fail` functions becomes `thingToDelete` so `destroy` will try to delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helps! If it is not too much trouble, could you help me with this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712446/parse-cloud-code-helper-function-not-working