# Parse Cloud Code Helper Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Here is the parse javascript cloud code I wrote. I want to find all objects in subclass "Example" having one like and then reset them as four. I have already established the Example class and Like column in the data browser. But the query didn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
function exampleFunction() {
  var Example = Parse.Object.extend("Example");
  var newObject = new Example();
  newObject.save(); // until here, the function works, it continues creating new objects
  var query = new Parse.Query(Example);
  query.equalTo('Like',1);
  query.find({
    success:function(result){
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          result[i].set('Like',4);
      }
    },
    error:function(error){

    }
  }) 
}

  Parse.Cloud.define("nice", function(request, response) {
      exampleFunction();
      response.success();
  });
```

I use this period of code on iOS device to trigger the cloud function:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"nice"
                   withParameters:@{}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                }
                            }];
```

Comment: You should `NSLog("Error: %@", error);` inside of the block so you get some more information, then update your question

Comment: I'll go with that. If you can find an error message it does help to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possible issues..

1. You are calling asynchronous methods and not giving them time to complete. That's where Parse Promises come in. You have to make sure to use the `then` function. See http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/
2. You are correctly setting 'Like' to 4, but you aren't saving the rows by calling `save`
3. You may not have any rows coming back from your query, they way to check that is to pass the number of rows found back through the success callback, which I am doing below

Try this below, noticing that the `.success` should return a result if you `NSLog(@"result %@",result)` from your objective-c. Also, the error should be coming through now as well because of `response.error(error)`

```
var Example = Parse.Object.extend("Example");

function exampleFunction() {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Example);
  query.equalTo('Like',1);
  return query.find().then(function(examplesLikedOnce){
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < examplesLikedOnce.length; i++) {
      var example = examplesLikedOnce[i];
      var promise = example.save({Like:4});
      promises.push(promise);
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
      return examplesLikedOnce.length;
    });
  }); 
}

Parse.Cloud.define("nice", function(request, response) {
    exampleFunction().then(function(numExamples){
      response.success("The number of Example objects with 1 like: "+numExamples);
    }, function(error){
      response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I tried your solution and it is still not working. i even set all object's ACL to publicWriteAccess true. And there is no error message in the console.

Comment: I also write another period of code,but it still not working, dont know why:https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8k23f5ja8fsffo/sample.js?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is still something wrong. The console in objective-C returns correctly:"result The number of Example objects with 1 like: 5", and the number always matches the number of objects in Example Class. i seems the query works but still, the number under Like doesn't change.

Comment: Also, i ran across this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580413/cant-write-non-current-user-objects-by-pfuser-currentuser  Should i bind all existing Parse objects' id to current user so that the parse server will let me to write existing parse objects. i tried adding useMasterKey() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just set up an Example class, uploaded that `nice` function, and ran it using curl and it worked for me.. hard to say what your issue is.. If parse wasn't allowing you to edit the rows, it would return an error that looks like this: \"This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on Example. You can change this setting in the Data Browser.\" so I don't think it is a permissions issue

Comment: I solved the problem finally after I found the big stupid mistake that I didn't realize the whole time! I added an beforeSave function that init the Like number to 1. So every time the save function called in example. the beforeSave will change the like back to 1.